# RecordMyDesktop doesn't work

Tags: video, recordmydesktop

I used to use RecordMyDesktop all the time with no problems. Now when I use it, what it records is choppy and poor quality:

[image: Example of video quality]

Any tips on how to fix it? If not, any other screen recorder recommendations?

Comment: If you can't get it fixed, I'd recommend OBS. It's designed mainly for recording and streaming games, but it's very functional, and can be used to record specific windows or your entire screen. You might have to use the unstable version if you're on 15.10 though.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I heard about _simplescreenrecorder_ and it's fantastic and does more than _RecordMyDesktop_. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I switched to "Simple Screen Recorder" worked immediately.

(only thing that need tweaking was that it was set to pulseaudio by default and I needed to switch that to alsa, but that setting is right there on the first page of the gui)

Comment: I tried out _simplescreenrecorder_ and it's amazing! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BulletProofBalloon - if this answer helped you, you can upvote or mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to tweak a few settings, otherwise you will need to ensure hardware acceleration and codecs via ffmpeg/avconv and gstreamer are available. Using these settings I have got it work quite well *(it outputs a OGV file @15 FPS, at roughly the same display size and quality as what I had)*:

[image]

[image]   [image]

You should get good results with the above - you can change most of these settings but ensure these to get the best results:

- Video and Audio quality at 100%
- 'Encode on the fly' disabled (probably optional, its speeds up things whilst recording but you have to wait afterwards)
- 'Zero Compression' and 'Full shots at every Frame' enabled (makes for larger size)
- FPS at 15 or above
- MIT-Shm enabled
- Selecting only a part of the screen may improve performance, otherwise try tweaking the display settings until it co-operates

By the way you can use [various keyboard shortcuts](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/app_a.php) - e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to stop.

In the above using [`gtk-recordMyDesktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gtk-recordmydesktop) v0.3.8 with Gnome 3.16 - it should be easy enough to get the same to happen with the Qt client or the command line client (see [`man recordmydeskop`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/recordmydesktop.1.html) for that)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I heard about _simplescreenrecorder_ and it's fantastic and does more than _RecordMyDesktop_. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!